# Compose filters without the presence of a collection?

Tags: c#

I think I might be having a temporary mental glitch here, so excuse me if this is a dumb question but I am wondering if one can compose filters so they can be applied to a collection:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        Func<int, bool> filter = GetFilter();
        IEnumerable<int> result = a.Where(filter);
    }

    private static Func<int, bool> GetFilter()
    {
        Func<int, bool> filter = c => c % 2 == 0;

        // What if I wanted to further refine my filter here?
        // For instance, add a ceiling of 10

        return filter;
    }
```

Comment: @Jonesy edited it,thanks - incidentally, the += doesn't get the correct result.. it doesn't bomb either... not sure what it does

Comment: @Jonesy Actually that doesn't work.  If you call `filter(1)` it returns `true` instead of `false`.  I believe it only returns the last delegate's return value.

Comment: whoops you are right, that result is incorrect.

Comment: @AaronAnodide A `Func` is just a delegate and you and use `+=` on delegates, making it a multicast delegate.  This is mainly used for events were the return is void, but it seems that if there is a return value it returns the value generated by the last delegate that was added.

Comment: Here's an interesting link about multicast delegates with return types http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356488/ccreating-multicast-delegate-with-boolean-return-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'd have to add a reference to the original filter to avoid a recursive call.

```
var previousFilter = filter;
filter = c => previousFilter(c) && c <= 10;
```

Comment: I actually ran into this problem.  How exactly does the recursion occur?

Answer (score 0):

```
return f => c <= 10 && filter(c);
```