# Return value based on multiple bool conditions

Tags: c#, .net

I have following case:

```
enum values{
go = 1,
stand = 2,
jump = 3,
run = 4,
go_stand=5,
go_jump=6,
go_run=7,
go_stand_jump=8,
… and so on 
Go_stand_jum_prun=17}

int select value(bool go, bool stand, bool jump, bool run)
{
}
```

Based on combination of bool values passed to the method I need to return appropriate value, meaning if go=true and the rest false 1 will returned if all parameters passed in will be true 17 will be returns, the same applies for all combinations in between. The Only idea I have it’s a lot of if and else if statements to evaluate possible combinations, which is sort of ugly. The question is there more elegant solution.

Thank you all!!!

Comment: What Language should this be? Not `C#` for sure...

Comment: Can you please detail the question? what value should you return ? The funciton you wrote is a Void.

Comment: how enum is related to boolean values? Can you please show how do you use booleans?

Comment: _I need to return appropriate value_ what is appropriate value? also your method signature is wrong.

Comment: Have you considered that using a `[Flags]` based `enum` might simpify things?

Comment: @MANIKANDANNAGALAKSHMI delegates in what way?

Comment: @user285682 don't think. don't ask. just use delegates! why? for simplicity of corse

Comment: this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356488/ccreating-multicast-delegate-with-boolean-return-type

Comment: In a real language like C, you'd write `return 1 * go + 2 * stand + 4 * jump + 8 * run;`, and set up your enumeration appropriately.

Comment: @Smartis It should be C#

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy emun is combination of parameters names. 4 parameters and enum all possible combinations of these parameters.

Comment: @user285682 Look at the answers for a valid C# method head. ;)

Comment: @JamesThorpe Thank frack someone else knows about the Flags attribute! I was starting to think it'd been deprecated or something :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply [FlagsAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to your enumeration:

```cs
[Flags]
public enum Activity
{
    None = 0,
    Go = 1,
    Stand = 2,
    Jump = 4,
    Run = 8,
}
```

And make use of the [conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.140).aspx) to construct your enumeration:

```cs
public static Activity CreateActivity(bool go, bool stand, bool jump, bool run)
{
    return
        (go    ? Activity.Go    : 0) |
        (stand ? Activity.Stand : 0) |
        (jump  ? Activity.Jump  : 0) |
        (run   ? Activity.Run   : 0);
}
```

Complete example:

```cs
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Activity goJump = Activity.Go | Activity.Jump;

        Activity activity =
            CreateActivity(
                go:    true,
                stand: false,
                jump:  true,
                run:   false);

        Console.WriteLine(activity == goJump); // prints "True"
    }

    public static Activity CreateActivity(bool go, bool stand, bool jump, bool run)
    {
        return
            (go    ? Activity.Go    : 0) |
            (stand ? Activity.Stand : 0) |
            (jump  ? Activity.Jump  : 0) |
            (run   ? Activity.Run   : 0);
    }
}

[Flags]
public enum Activity
{
    None = 0,
    Go = 1,
    Stand = 2,
    Jump = 4,
    Run = 8,
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To achieve this you have to modify your `enum`

```
enum values {
    none = 0,
    go =  ( 1 << 0 ), // 1
    stand = ( 1 << 1 ), // 2
    jump =  ( 1 << 2 ), // 4,
    run = ( 1 << 3 ), // 8
    go_jump = go | jump
}
```

Then in your method:

```
values GetValues(bool go, bool stand, bool jump, bool run)
{
    values result = values.none;
    if( go )
        result |= values.go;

    if( stand )
        result |= values.stand;

    // and so on...

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You have to admit it was easier in 1978, but have an upvote all the same.

Comment: You should use the Flags attribute. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you're working with enums as bit fields in .net then it's incorrect without the flags attribute. If you check my answer you'll see that you don't have to define every combination of enum values manually, and yet the output still shows separate fields `Console.WriteLine(value2); //Stand, Jump, Run`. The fact that your enum has to declare every possible combination makes it more prone to errors (objectively) and less readable (subjectively).

Comment: @AndyJ I have to admit my solution is "Anty-Idot" solution because you have to get some knowledge about bitwise operators and you have to specify every possible combination which you cannot using `FlagsAttribute`. For some examples it's okay to use `FlagsAttribute` but i doubt that you can `stand | jump`...

Comment: I love the use of the shift operators to demonstrate what is really going on rather than just using 1, 2, 4, 8.

Comment: @m.rogalski That's a good point about only certain combinations being valid.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [flags enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to allow combining the values into a single enum value.

> Indicates that an enumeration can be treated as a bit field; that is, a set of flags.

Here's an example:
([Dot Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ene31C))

```
using System;

[Flags]
public enum Value
{
    None = 0,
    Go = 1,
    Stand = 2,
    Jump = 4,
    Run = 8
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {   
        var value1 = CreateValue(true, false, true, false);
        var value2 = CreateValue(false, true, true, true);

        Console.WriteLine(value1); //Go, Jump
        Console.WriteLine(value2); //Stand, Jump, Run
    }

    public static Value CreateValue(bool go, bool stand, bool jump, bool run)
    {
        var value = Value.None;

        if(go)
            value |= Value.Go;

        if(stand)
            value |= Value.Stand;

        if(jump)
            value |= Value.Jump;

        if(run)
            value |= Value.Run;

        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: you missed the `go_stand_jump` and other flags

Comment: @Toshi -- No. Re-read the answer.  And read the linked flags MSDN.

Comment: @Toshi The Flags attribute handles that. If you run the code (follow the DotNetFiddle link) then you'll see the console outputs the contents of the values. value2 is "Stand, Jump, Run".

Answer (score 2):

You can use bit-wise math.  For instance, here is your class:

```
class MyClass
{
    [Flags]
    public enum Values
    {
        Go = 1,
        Stand = 2,
        Jump = 4,
        Run = 8
    }

    public Values Select(bool go, bool stand, bool jump, bool run)
    {
        Values ret = 0;
        if (go) ret = (ret | Values.Go);
        if (stand) ret = (ret | Values.Stand);
        if (jump) ret = (ret | Values.Jump);
        if (run) ret = (ret | Values.Run);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

And here is how you'd use it:

```
var mc = new MyClass();
MyClass.Values y = mc.Select(true, false, true, true);
bool isStand = (y & MyClass.Values.Stand) == MyClass.Values.Stand; // false
bool isJump = (y & MyClass.Values.Jump) == MyClass.Values.Jump; // true
```

Comment: I've got to ask why 2, 4, 8 and 64 rather than the more traditional 1,2,4,8?

Comment: Who knows.  Just my standard I guess.  Never given much thought.

Comment: Also I've just noticed that you are returning an int rather than the enum. Is this because you aren't familiar with flags enums (I'd assume so but you may have a better reason to use an int instead)?

Comment: Yeah I didn't know about that attribute before.  When did that come about?  I've been doing it like this in one form or another forever and mostly in VB.NET and other VB flavors.

Comment: Pretty sure its been in .net from the start but I may be wrong. Its certainly nothing that new. Glad you've learned something new today! :)

Comment: @Chris -- Is the point only to alert callers that the enum should be treated as bitwise values?  I skimmed the docs but I can't see how the compiler would use that to do anything.

Comment: There is the Enum.HasFlag (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag(v=vs.110).aspx) method that says it shouldn't be used on an enum that doesn't have the flags attribute set. I have no idea if it forces that behaviour though.

Comment: The other good thing is in the locals/autos/watch windows.  It shows the actual values instead of just the int value.

Comment: I would love to know what the DV is for....Although everyone's got a DV so it was probably a troll..

Comment: @rory.ap Apparently I'm so special I got two \o/ It's a shame so few people leave feedback on how to fix the cause of the DV, it'd be nice to know what to improve on.

Comment: @AndyJ -- I doubt it was about a problem.  People just love to exercise their power to damage your rep and reduce your work towards tag privileges.

Answer (score 0):

this pseudo code should work if you arrange your values that are not shown "correctly" if they are not and start with 0, instead of 1.   .

```
int select value(bool go, bool stand, bool jump, bool run)
 {
  return (int) runx2^3 + (int)jumpx2^2 + (int) standx2^1 + (int) go;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Nothing = 0,
    Run = 1,
    Jump = 2,
    Stand = 4,
    Go = 8,
    RunJump = Run + Jump,
    RunStand = Run + Stand,
    ...
}

public MyEnum GetValue(bool go, bool stand, bool jump, bool run)
{
    // true, true, true, true is 1111
    // true, true, true, false is 1110
    var returnValue = (go ? 1 << 3 : 0) + (stand ? 1 << 2 : 0) + (jump ? 1 << 1 : 0) + (run ? 1 : 0);

    return (MyEnum)returnValue;
}
```